# How to make an android application communicate with database even if the app is closed

Tags: database, android-studio, mobile-development, android-developer-api

i want to know how the app keeps intereacting with database even if the app is closed .

**for exemple :**
an application of any game , it let you play one game for 1 ticket .. and when there is no tickets left it will give you a ticket every 15 minuts , so the user closes the app and then comebacks after (let's say 5 hours) and he finds the tickets charged .
how this could be possible in android studio ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to do this client side, I would not recommend creating a background process that communicates with the server every time, but instead calculate the time in between the time when the user stopped playing the game and the time he played next time. Then you would reward them based on the time that passed.

Comment: how this could be done ? 
and is there are any other ways to do this ? from the database ?